# Creating a pandas.Series in the latest version of python pandas doesn't work in Matlab

Tags: python, pandas, matlab

I am calling several python libraries in Matlab and am now having trouble using the latest version of pandas (ver 0.23.x) https://pandas.pydata.org/ . Conversely, pandas 0.22.x works fine.

Note that the problem doesn't exist in python.

To reproduce:

```
% set desired python environment
pyversion(pypath)

% try to create a pandas series
py.pandas.Series(1)

Error using py.pandas.Series
Class 'py.pandas.core.series.Series' is not allowed to define a 'cat' method.
```

Has anyone experienced this?

I noticed that pandas has moved the CategoricalAccessor (which 'cat' refers to) from pandas.core.series.CategoricalAccessor to pandas.core.arrays.categorical.CategoricalAccessor. Maybe this is related?

Any help on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this on R2018b with python 3.6.6 and pandas 0.23.4, on Win10 x64.

What you suggest is very likely related, since pandas' `cat` likely interferes with MATLAB's `cat` which is used for *concatenation*.

I would advise you to create a new virtual environment, with the correct version of pandas, and have MATLAB use *that* (via the `pyversion` command). After all, this is exactly what virtual environments are for. See also [this documentation article](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I already am running two different envs (one for each pandas version), however, I would like to use the latest version of pandas in the future. Is that simply not possible at the moment, or what are my options here?

Comment: Perhaps you could submit a bug report to MathWorks, and they would be able to provide a workaround, or incorporate a fix in the coming versions. You can either do that or modify pandas by yourself to revert the offending change (or perhaps rename the offending function/package). Perhaps you could nest the `Series` object in your own python class, so that MATLAB doesn't try to parse its method names and thus never "realizes" that an issue exists....